# PHP form redirect from a popup

Tags: javascript, redirect, dom-events

I have a basic html form with some inputs.  My file is "form.php" and once the data is sent to the form, I want to do a popup and then redirect to my homepage.  For whatever reason, this code

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",function(){
   alertIt();
   return redirect(); 
   },false);

   function redirect(){
       window.location.replace = "index.html" ;
   }

   function alertIt(){
     alert("Thank you for your feedback!");
   }
</script>
```

results in a working popup, but once the popup appears, it takes me to `"/form.php"` instead of redirecting me to index.html.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `window.location.replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you send the form to the php file and then use a `header("Location: index.html");` to redirect to index?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `false` from the event handler to prevent the default action of the event, which submits the form and reloads the result.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",function(){
    alertIt();
    redirect(); 
    return false;
},false);
```

Also, your `redirect` function is wrong. `window.location.replace` is a function you should call, not a property you assign; the property is `window.location.href`.

Comment: ah ok this makes sense.  i changed this method as well as the window.location.replace but it is still redirecting me to form.php....

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the page to cancel the default action of the form.

The easiest way to do this, with your existing code, you would be to simply return false from your `redirect()` function.

```
function redirect() {
    return false;
}
```

A better approach might be to use the `event` object's `preventDefault()` method:

```
var submitHandler = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false; //For older browsers

    alertIt();
    redirect();

    return false;
};

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, false);

function redirect(){
    window.location.href = "index.html";
}

function alertIt(){
   alert("Thank you for your feedback!");
}
```

Please note that you were simply replacing the window's location, not telling it to redirect.

```
window.location.replace = "index.html"; //This sets the new location, but doesn't redirect
```

Compared to

```
window.location.href = "index.html"; //This causes the page to redirect immediately.
```

Comment: -1. Why `window.location.replace = "index.html";`? It replaces the function instead of calling it.

Comment: @Oleg That's not my code - that's the OP's code...don't -1 me for that.